# Get counts of instances of values inside an array of objects (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb

Say I have a bunch of documents in a collection called `books`:

```json
books: [
  {
    title: 'book title',
    genres: [
      {
        id: 1
        name: 'fiction',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'mystery',
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'another book',
    genres: [
      {
        id: 1
        name: 'fiction',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'fantasy',
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to return a list of genres, grouped by how often they appear:

```json
[
  {
    id: 1,
    count: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    count: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    count: 1,
  }
]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have found the answer:

```
db.books.aggregate({ $unwind: { "path": "$genres" }}, { $group: { "_id": "$genres.id", "count": { $sum: 1 }}}, { $sort: { "count": -1 }})
```